# Could not find android-maven-gradle-plugin.jar while updating android studio 3.0.1 to 3.1

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-studio-3.1

I am facing with following issue while updating android studio 3.0.1 to 3.1

Could not find android-maven-gradle-plugin.jar (com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/1.5/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.jar

Below is my build.gradle

```kotlin
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: In the new ver. gradle 7.0.2 , see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/70811778/12272687

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got solution,
error resolved by updating

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
```

**In gradle-wrapper.properties use this :**

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

and update **buildToolsVersion** to **27.0.3**

Answer (score 1):

**Gradle Android Maven plugin**

To use the android-maven-gradle-plugin, just apply the plugin in your android-library project. Also add the plugin classpath dependency to the buildScript.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

**OR use gradle 2.1**

```
plugins {
 id "com.github.dcendents.android-maven" version "2.0"
}
```

You can set the maven groupId and version in the script build.gradle:

```
group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0'
```

set in settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'artifact'
```